# Old UIUC Complex Comp Question - Convergent subsequences in a family of functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F} = \{f \in H(D) : \int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{it})| \leq 1\}$ where (D) is the unit disk centered at the origin.

(a) Prove that every sequence $\{f_n\}$ where $f_n \in \mathcal{F}$ has a subsequence converging on compact subsets of $D$.

(b) Does the limit of the subsequence in (a)  have to be in $\mathcal{F}$? Justify your claim.

I'm uncertain as to how to start this problem, let alone finish it. I'd guess that it has something to do with normal families of functions, but I have no idea how to go about solving it. Any suggestions please?.

Comment: Are the functions $f\in\mathcal{F}$ continuous on the closure $\overline{D}$?

Comment: Yes, they are continuous on the boundary of D.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be a compact set contained in $D$. Observe that since any point in $K$ is at positive distance from $\partial D$, it follows from compactness that $\inf_{z\in K, w\in\partial D}\left|z-w\right|\geq\delta>0$, where $\delta$ depends on $K$. For $f\in \mathcal{F}$, we have by the Cauchy integral formula the estimate

$$\left|f(z)\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial D}\dfrac{\left|f(z)\right|}{\inf_{z\in K}\left|z-w\right|}\left|dw\right|\leq\delta^{-1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|f(e^{it})\right|dt\leq\delta^{-1}, \qquad\forall z\in D$$

This shows that $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of functions which is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $D$. Montel's theorem implies that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family. This should take of (a). For (b), Weierstrass's theorem implies that the limit function is holomorphic on $D$ and continuous on $\overline{D}$. The inequality bit follows from dominated convergence.